# Reboot to another grub entry

Tags: grub2

I need to use Windows for 1 task. Thus I made a script to reboot in another boot entry (for the next reboot only):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $UID != 0 ]] ; then
    sudo $0 $@
    exit $?
fi

ENTRY=$(gawk -F "'" '/menuentry / {print $2}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep "Windows Boot Manager.*")

grub-reboot "$ENTRY"
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    exit 1
fi

if zenity --question --title="Reboot Now ?" --text="Are you ready to reboot now ?" --no-wrap ; then
    shutdown -r now
fi
```

I'd like to be able to call it in the power menu along with sleep, shutdown, close session... I guess I have to write some gnome-shell-extension ? As I'm new to gnome shell extensions I'd like to know where to start ? How can I add/modify these menu entries ?

By the way I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I would not do this and just add it to the desktop so you can click it and have it execute. Or put it into a key combination (like control-alt-7)

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/p-e-w/argos can partially fit your needs, because you can create a new item in the top bar. This is only a suggestion, I have never used it.